# USB webcam connected to MacBook through Dell monitor is sporadically undetected

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, webcam

My setup is as follow:

- MacBook Pro M1 Max (macOS 12.5)
- External monitor: Dell P3421W
- USB webcam connected to USB-A port in monitor, monitor is connected to Macbook via USB-C.

My issue is that every so often the webcam is not detected by the laptop. But after I disconnect and reconnect it, it is detected and working properly. Then after the laptop goes to sleep, it is often not recognized again until I disconnect and reconnect.

I tried few webcams - all have the same issue, so that leads me to think the issue is somewhere between the monitor and laptop? Is that a known issue? Any idea how to debug it?

Comment: Update: Using the most up to date driver, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

There is a firmware update available for your monitor claiming to fix USB issues with Macbooks:

```
Fixes & Enhancements
...
2. Fix Apple Macbook USB compatibility issues.
...
```

You can find the update package on the [Dell support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-p3421w-monitor/drivers).

Comment: That didn't help sadly. I still have the same issue after upgrading the monitor's firmware.

Comment: @duduamar Did you also install the manufacturers drivers?

Comment: What do you mean? I installed the latest firmware update from Dell

Comment: @duduamar The site I've linked contains links to 3 different packages. The firmware update, Dell Display Manager, and Driver for Dell P3421W Monitor

Comment: I only see the firmware update in that link

Comment: @duduamar The [support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-p3421w-monitor/drivers) contains links to the [firmware](https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-at/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=0v4hw&oscode=wt32a&productcode=dell-p3421w-monitor), [dell display manager](https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-at/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=v9rk0&oscode=wt32a&productcode=dell-p3421w-monitor) and a [driver](https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-at/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=dk9m6&oscode=wt32a&productcode=dell-p3421w-monitor).

Comment: Thats weird - in your link I have a single result - the updated driver

Comment: your link direct to the Austrian page, and I still get "driver not found" error (in German?), maybe it's not available in US?

Comment: @duduamar My mistake. The utility only exists for windows, not macos.